# How to print a portion of an HTML page?

Tags: html, css, printing

I have an html page i want to print a portion of this html page, I know a javascript function to print a page,

```
onClick="javascript:window.print(); return false;
```

but how can I print a portion of a page?

If anyone has an idea, please share it with me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use a separate css for the print media. This allows you to hide/show portions of the page when it gets printed.

html :

```
<div class="dont-print-that">
   blah
</div>
print this!
```

include:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

print.css

```
.dont-print-that{display:none;}
```

The other solution is to open a new window with only the content you want to print. You could either do that in a popup or an iframe. Personally I find the CSS solution more elegant, but that's up to you.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done using JavaScript and iframes:

1. Dump the innerHTML of the container into the iFrame (plus any print-specific CSS
2. print the iFrame contents.

Try it out in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zo14p0ut/)

You can see the code here, but it won't work due to what are probably security limitations in StackOverflow's renderer.

```js
const printButton = document.getElementById('print-button');

printButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
  // build the new HTML page
  const content = document.getElementById('name-card').innerHTML;
  const printHtml = `<html>
      <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title>Name Card</title>
      </head>
      <body>${content}</body>
  </html>`;
      
  // get the iframe
  let iFrame = document.getElementById('print-iframe');
  
  // set the iFrame contents and print
  iFrame.contentDocument.body.innerHTML = printHtml;
  iFrame.focus();
    iFrame.contentWindow.print();
  
});
```

```html
<h1>Print your name badge</h1>
<div id="name-card" class="card">
  <p>Hello my name is</p>
  <h2>Max Powers</h2>
</div>
<p>You will be required to wear your name badge at all times</p>
<a id="print-button" class="btn btn-primary">Print</a>

<iframe id="print-iframe" width="0" height="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement multiple "Print this section" features on a page, then print media stylesheets (described in other answers) are the way forward…

… but combine that with [alternative stylesheets](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/alternate/) so you can switch to one for each section.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a CSS style to hide everything but what you want printed for `media="print"` using Javascript.

You can also load the page in another window or a [hidden] `<iframe>` and print that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer, but there's no need to use javascript. Browsers repaint the page using the correct css when printing.

Comment: @Alsciende, I know that.  I understood the question as wanting to print only a very small portion of the document, not the entire document.  I meant he can insert the CSS rules for the print medium before printing starts so everything except that small portion is hidden.