# how to print a web page 

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to print a portion of an HTML page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461275/how-to-print-a-portion-of-an-html-page)

I am making a quotation online. I want the user to be able to print it.

I have seen my exact requirement on [this webpage](http://www.solar-estimate.org/index.php). On this web page, there is a print option. When the user clicks on print it will send a print command to the printer if a printer is attached.

Does anyone know how can I do that?

Comment: Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26114555/3944217

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
<button id="printbutton" onclick="window.print();" />
```

Comment: A `media="print"` stylesheet never goes astray either

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite confused by your question...

To trigger a print programatically with JavaScript (PHP won't help you much), you can call `window.print()` :

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.print()" />
```

Comment: thanx u gt my point i am exactly wanting this