# How do i print all image in web page? (Printer)

Tags: javascript, php, xampp

I have a this code

```
<?php echo '<img border="1" src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($row['image']) . '"  ;/>'; ?></br>
```

How do I print the img in a printer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to print a web page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878562/how-to-print-a-web-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript `print()` function can be called to open the print dialog in the browser. You could try adding a script element to your page that calls print:

```
<script type="text/javascript">print();</script>
```

I'm not sure how the timing would work, but you might need to do it on the onload event instead

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        print();
    };
</script>
```

or perhaps a `setTimeout` to delay the print call for a moment until the page is fully rendered.

Comment: Sir. The url are also being printed. Is it possible that the url will not be printed?

Comment: @SchyronSy see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585254/how-to-remove-the-url-from-the-printing-page